# MySQL aggregate MAX

Tags: mysql, max, aggregate-functions, alias

I have a problem with the aggregation of the column, which was created by alias.

```
SELECT IF(PPU.id IS NOT NULL, PPU.price, PP.price) AS price, MAX(price) AS max FROM ...
```

The problem occurs because of column price, that is obtained in both PP and PPU tables. When the price column is renamed "price1" there is a bug that says this column does not exist. Is it possible to use MAX for alias?

Comment: Only with HAVING, or otherwise with WHERE if used in a subquery's 'superquery'. But why not show us the whole query.

Comment: did you try to put the if clause in the MAX function?